# Build library libtorrent debian and link it to program c++

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I always have problems when building libraries and linking them, so I hope someone can give me a hand.

I downloaded libtorrent from [here](http://www.libtorrent.org/) and I've built it like they explain [here](http://file:///home/ubuntuk/workspaces/streamer/Import/libtorrent/docs/building.html) in the `building with autotools` section (skipping step 1). The building process was successfull I think, but when I did `make check` the output was:

```
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for libtorrent-rasterbar 1.0.5
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 0
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

Maybe it should say: total X?

I did a little program where I added `#include <libtorrent/session.hpp>` and when I compile with `g++ file.cpp -o file` it says `libtorrent/session.hpp: No such file or directory`.

Should I add some flags to g++ such as `-lpthread` for other projects and thinks like that?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
When installing without building using `sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev` and compiling my main.cpp file I get this error:

```
g++ main.cpp -o file
In file included from /usr/include/libtorrent/session.hpp:49:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/libtorrent/config.hpp:46:2: error: #error you must define either BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION or BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK in your project in order for asio's declarations to be correct. If you're linking dynamically against libtorrent, define BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK otherwise BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION. You can also use pkg-config or boost build, to automatically apply these defines
#error you must define either BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION or BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK in your project in \
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Modified the `main.cpp` file to add the the following above the libtorrent `#include` directives:

```
#ifndef BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK
#endif
```

But then I have this problem:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
/tmp/ccM2ItFb.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to  `libtorrent::default_storage_constructor(libtorrent::file_storage const&, libtorrent::file_storage const*, std::string const&, libtorrent::file_pool&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `libtorrent::session::~session()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `libtorrent::session::~session()'
/tmp/ccM2ItFb.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `boost::asio::error::get_netdb_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `boost::asio::error::get_addrinfo_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `boost::asio::error::get_misc_category()'
/tmp/ccM2ItFb.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
main.cpp (.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccM2ItFb.o: In function `libtorrent::session::session(libtorrent::fingerprint const&, int, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN10libtorrent7sessionC2ERKNS_11fingerprintEij[_ZN10libtorrent7sessionC5ERKNS_11fingerprintEij]+0x3c): undefined reference to `libtorrent::rel_clocktime_pools_nolog_resolvecountries_deprecated_dht_ext_()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN10libtorrent7sessionC2ERKNS_11fingerprintEij[_ZN10libtorrent7sessionC5ERKNS_11fingerprintEij]+0x75): undefined reference to `libtorrent::session::init(std::pair<int, int>, char const*, libtorrent::fingerprint const&, int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccM2ItFb.o: In function `void boost::checked_delete<libtorrent::torrent_info const>(libtorrent::torrent_info const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost14checked_deleteIKN10libtorrent12torrent_infoEEEvPT_[_ZN5boost14checked_deleteIKN10libtorrent12torrent_infoEEEvPT_]+0x1a): undefined reference to `libtorrent::torrent_info::~torrent_info()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also tried compiling using: `g++ -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread main.cpp` with the same result.

**UPDATE 3:**

I was able to solve the problem. I had to compile using: 
`g++ -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread main.cpp` and add also the link library `-ltorrent-rasterbar`

Comment: Perhaps you didn't install the library ? usually done with `make install` , see if you can figure out through its output where it's installed, so you at least know where the header files and library files are on your disk

Comment: Instead of compiling it yourself, BTW, you could use the version provided by Debian: `apt install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev`

Comment: You can use a command like: find / -name session.hpp -print, to find the location on the session.hpp.  Then on g++ command add a parameter of the form -I/path/to/session.hpp.

Comment: okey, that's what I did Wyzard. But I get an error with Boost now, because I have to link asio and libtorrent I guess... (Updated the question)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've compiled the library but not actually installed it anywhere.  An `#include` directive looks in `/usr/include` by default, but the libtorrent headers are somewhere in the directory where you built the library.  You'll need to either install the library's files into the system directories, or give the compiler an `-I` option pointing to the libtorrent build directory.  (You'll probably also need an `-L` option when linking, for the same reason.)

Comment: Now I was able to add it in there, but still have some problems. Thanks for the help!